# How can a get OSM data in QGIS in a way that shows the direction of a road as it would in JOSM?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-2

I am trying to download OSM data into QGIS in a way that is as close as possible to what it looks like in JOSM. I am doing a visual comparison between OSM data and satellite images. One of the things I am looking at is comparing if one-ways are mapped correctly. How can I get the OSM data in QGIS in a way that shows the direction of a road as it would in JOSM?

Comment: If you use OSM tile server, i think you can't do it. What about to download OSM vector data and add style? (http://www.geofabrik.de/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get OSM data into QGIS with the QuickOSM plugin.

Under `Web -> QuickOSM -> QuickOSM`, go to the `OSM file` section. Look for the path to the osmconf.ini file, search it with your explorer, and open it with a good text editor like notepad++.

In the [lines] section, go to the `attributes` line, and add `,oneway` at the end.
Save the file and close it.

Back in the QuickOSM panel, go to the  `Quick query` tab and enter `highway` in the key field. Using the Openlayers plugin, navigate to your place of interest, and run the query.

You can remove the node and multipolygon layers, and save the temporary lines layer to a shapefile on disk.

Now you need a special style for the oneways.

Rightclick on the lines layer, `Properties...`, go to the `Styles` tab, and change the style from `Single Symbol` to `Categorized` on column `oneway`. Click on `Classify`and see what values you get.

In the line with `yes`, double-click on the symbol, and add a new line with the green +. Select the added line, change the symbol layer type from `Simple line` to `Marker line`. select the `Simple Marker`line, and select `>`as the symbol.

If you have oneways with `-1` or value, you have to rotate the symbol by 180°.
You might have a look at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:oneway#Implied_oneway_restriction too.

You can style the highways with empty `oneway` field different, and you will get this result:

[image]

If you don't want to see footways etc, you can filter the dataset with

```
NOT ("highway"  = 'bridleway'  OR "highway" = 'cycleway' OR "highway" = 'footway' OR "highway" = 'path' OR "highway" = 'steps' OR "highway" = 'track')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really deeply appreciate the help! Very useful.

Comment: How can I show the nodes that are at the intersection of two roads? This is useful, because how will I know by just looking at the downloaded data from OSM into QGIS that the crossing of the two roads are an intersection or a bridge? In OSM a node shows that there is an intersection and that a car can turn from the one road onto the other, if the node is not there a car cannot turn, this is the case with a bridge.

Comment: This can be determined by the `layer` tag. But on this site there should be one question per topic, so you better open up a new one.